# how to downgrade R version using brew in MAC

Tags: r, homebrew

I installed R using brew in Mac.

like this...

```
brew install R
```

The above command installs the latest version of R.

But I want to change the R version to 3.6.3.

So I tried as below, but the following error occurs.

```
brew install R@3.6.3
```

[image]

How can i downgrade the version of R?